# format method does not assign values to a string when importing as global variable

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I defined some variables inside a file named `queries.py` and import them inside another file named `views.py`. The problem is python format does not assign values of each variable to the corresponding placeholder. Consider following lines of code :

```
queries.py

main_where_query = ''' where users.deleted_account is null
        and length(users.phone_number) > 2
        and length(users.phone_number) < 20
        and users.phone_number not like '+98888888%'
    '''

messages_where_query = """{0} 
                            and messages.date>'{1}' 
                            and messages.date<'{2}'
                        """
```

```
views.py

from .queries import *
def get_activity(request):
    global main_where_query
    global messages_where_query
    messages_where_query.format(main_where_query, str(start_date), str(end_date))
    ....
```

and the output is :

```
select count(messages.message_id) from messages
                join users on users.id = messages.sender
                {0} 
                            and messages.date>'{1}' 
                            and messages.date<'{2}'

                and messages.media_type = 0
```

As you can see all the placeholders are untouched like **{0} {1} {2}**.I'm sure that those variables are not empty and imported correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem happens because you are formatting `messages_where_query` in place which isn't the way `format` works. You need to set `messages_where_query` to itself after formatting. Also, you don't need to use `global` keyword; you have imported them already from another file, so they aren't global variables per se

Your `views.py` script should look like this:

```
from .queries import *
def get_activity(request):
    global main_where_query
    global messages_where_query
    messages_where_query = \
        messages_where_query.format(main_where_query, str(start_date), str(end_date))
    ....
```